# What std::_lockit does?

Tags: c++, performance, std

I checked performance of c++ project and results are not so clear to me.
`std::_lockit::int()` has over 20% of exclusive samples. What does it do and how do I avoid overusing it? I have a lot of things created with `std::vector`, so there is a hope that these are connected.

Comment: Did you enable all optimizations and disable debugging?

Comment: Yes I use /Ox to build.

Comment: Well, it's a Microsoft-specific internal thing... might be better to consult the compiler manual. It's nothing to do with standard C++.

Comment: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/multithreaded-dll-what-going-std-lockit-help-11610292.html#r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

_Lockit is commonly used in Microsoft's implementation of the STL for debugging iterators.  In production environments these can be the cause of significant performance bottlenecks while iterating over containers with a large number of elements.

Debugging iterators can be disabled by defining the macros `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` and `_SECURE_SCL` as `0` in your code, or Visual Studio project properties.

Related: [Unnecessary locking in STL? (Visual C++ Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006883/unnecessary-locking-in-stl-visual-c-express)